# issue with css show hide with dynamic id'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With the following link

the things work properly

http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/

Code for the above is:

```
<div class="purchasing-tips">
<div id="slender-trigger">nnnn</div> 
                   <div id="slender"></div>
</div>

$("#slender-trigger").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $("#slender").show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $("#slender").hide();
});

#slender-trigger {
background-color: #CCC;
height: 80px;
width: 40px;
margin-left: 70px;
margin-top: 50px;
position: absolute;
}
#slender {
font-family: 'Strait', sans-serif;
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
border: thin dotted #F00;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 100px;
display: none;  
}
```

now, if i enable the dynamic ids with this, it just stop showing the div box on hover, is there some issue

please guide, send update is here

http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1292/

that does not work

Comment: Why arnt you just using CSS for this.   .image:hover .slender{display:block}

Comment: The jQuery in your not working example makes little sense. You split the class on a tilde when none of the classes have one. Then you attempt to select other elements that don't exist.

Comment: Your question seems to be about the event not triggering when ID is dynamically assigned. If the id attribute is set after the page loads, then the event handler (.on) will not bind to the element. You might find this link on event delegation helpful: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @GifCo wth css:, could u explain more

Comment: @soft_spo see here for css only http://jsfiddle.net/zanbffxa/

Comment: Hi, Can i handle the hovering imaging to show just after the elemt, without taking extra space in css

Comment: very cool @GifCo, how to give you 100+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code was not properly written.

```
   $(".image").on("mouseenter", function() {
          var pop = $(this).next().show();

    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
             var pop = $(this).next().hide();
   });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1293/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use this instead of your code

```
    $(".image").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).find('.slender').show();

    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).find('.slender').hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working (aside from the obvious errors like selecting the class instead of the id attribute, including a random hyphen in your reconstructed id, and not including the ~ in your reconstructed id) is that a CSS id can't include a tilde.  If you replace the ~ with a hyphen (-) (and fix the other errors), your code works, although one of the other solutions might serve you better anyway.

```
$("#popup-"+pID).show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RBJ9R/1294/